# Application problem with cycle form beans

Tags: java, spring

My application won't start with the message :

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

bookController 
   ↓

bookServiceImpl

┌─────┐

bookCommandToBook

↑           ↓
authorCommandToAuthor

└─────┘

**BookController**

```
package pl.springwebapp.webapp.controller;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import pl.springwebapp.webapp.command.BookCommand;
import pl.springwebapp.webapp.service.BookService;

@Slf4j
@Controller
public class BookController {
private BookService bookService;

public BookController(BookService bookService) {
    this.bookService = bookService;
}

@RequestMapping("/book/show/{id}")
public String showDescriptionById(@PathVariable long id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("book",bookService.findByID(id));
    return "/book/show";
}

@RequestMapping("book/new")
public String newBook(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("book", new BookCommand());

    return  "book/bookform";
}

@PostMapping
@RequestMapping(name = "book")
public String saveOrUpdate(@ModelAttribute BookCommand bookCommand){
    bookService.saveBookCommand(bookCommand);
    return "redirect:/index";
}
}
```

**BookServiceImpl**

```
package pl.springwebapp.webapp.service;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import pl.springwebapp.webapp.command.BookCommand;
import pl.springwebapp.webapp.converter.BookCommandToBook;
import pl.springwebapp.webapp.converter.BookToBookCommand;
import pl.springwebapp.webapp.model.Book;
import pl.springwebapp.webapp.repository.BookRepository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {

private BookRepository bookRepository;
private BookCommandToBook  bookCommandToBook;
private BookToBookCommand bookToBookCommand;

public BookServiceImpl(BookRepository bookRepository, BookCommandToBook bookCommandToBook, BookToBookCommand bookToBookCommand) {
    this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    this.bookCommandToBook = bookCommandToBook;
    this.bookToBookCommand = bookToBookCommand;
}

@Override
public Set<Book> getBooks(){
    Set<Book> bookSet = new HashSet<>();
    bookRepository.findAll().iterator().forEachRemaining(bookSet::add);
    return bookSet;
}

@Override
public Book findByID(long id) {
    Optional<Book> optionalBook = bookRepository.findById((id));
    if(!optionalBook.isPresent()){
        throw new RuntimeException("Book not found");
    }
    return optionalBook.get();
}

@Transactional
@Override
public BookCommand saveBookCommand(BookCommand bookCommand) {
    Book receivedBook = bookCommandToBook.convert(bookCommand);
    Book savedBook = bookRepository.save(receivedBook);
    return bookToBookCommand.convert(savedBook);
}
}
```

**BookCommandToBook**

```
package pl.springwebapp.webapp.converter;

import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import pl.springwebapp.webapp.command.BookCommand;
import pl.springwebapp.webapp.model.Book;


@Component
public class BookCommandToBook implements Converter<BookCommand, Book> {

private AuthorCommandToAuthor authorConverter;
private CategoryCommandToCategory categoryConverter;

public BookCommandToBook(AuthorCommandToAuthor authorConverter, CategoryCommandToCategory categoryConverter) {
    this.authorConverter = authorConverter;
    this.categoryConverter = categoryConverter;
}


@Override
public Book convert(BookCommand bookCommand) {
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setId(bookCommand.getId());
    book.setTitle(bookCommand.getTitle());
    book.setIsbn(bookCommand.getIsbn());
    book.setDescription(bookCommand.getDescription());
    book.setAuthor(authorConverter.convert(bookCommand.getAuthor()));

   if(bookCommand.getCategorySet() != null && bookCommand.getCategorySet().size() > 0 ){
        bookCommand.getCategorySet().forEach(categoryCommand -> book.getCategories().add(categoryConverter.convert(categoryCommand)));
    }

    return book;
}
}
```

**AuthorCommandToAuthor**

```
package pl.springwebapp.webapp.converter;

import lombok.Synchronized;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import pl.springwebapp.webapp.command.AuthorCommand;
import pl.springwebapp.webapp.model.Author;


@Component
public class AuthorCommandToAuthor implements Converter<AuthorCommand, Author> {

private BookCommandToBook bookConverter;

public AuthorCommandToAuthor(BookCommandToBook bookConverter) {
    this.bookConverter = bookConverter;
}

@Synchronized
@Override
   public Author convert(AuthorCommand authorCommand) {
    if(authorCommand==null){
        return null;
    }
    Author author = new Author();
    author.setId(authorCommand.getId());
    author.setName(authorCommand.getName());
    author.setLastName(authorCommand.getLastName());

    if(authorCommand.getBookCommandSet() != null && authorCommand.getBookCommandSet().size() > 0){
        authorCommand.getBookCommandSet()
                .forEach(bookCommand -> author.getBooks().add(bookConverter.convert(bookCommand)));
    }

    return author;
}
}
```

**AuthorCommand**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AuthorCommand {
private long id;
private String name;
private String lastName;
private Set<BookCommand> bookCommandSet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**BookCommand**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BookCommand {
private long id;
private String title;
private String isbn;
private String description;
private Set<CategoryCommand> categorySet = new HashSet<>();
private AuthorCommand author;
}
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Instead of constructor injection, you can use setter injection which can lazily intialize your beans. But you should try improving your design to avoid cyclic dependency.

Comment: All answers are correct, and to have them all in one post check  [Circular Dependencies](https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a cycle in your application context. That means that one bean depends on another and vice versa. Spring will be unable to create those beans, since one bean always has to be created first. More specifically, `AuthorCommandToAuthor` requires `BookCommandToBook` and `BookCommandToBook` requires `AuthorCommandToAuthor`.

To solve your problem, refactor shared code to a thrid component and inject it into both dependencies. This will eliminate the cycle.